# Different zoom levels targeting same media query

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where a certain element on the page is accepting the same media query when zoomed to 90% and also to 250%. This is resulting in an issue where I am unable to target both and its making the element look bad.

```
@media (max-width:2133px) {
    #slider button.right {
        right: -80px;
        /* right: -25px;*/
    }
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
    #slider button.right {
        right: -25px;
    }
}

<section id="slider">
    <button class="right">
        <span class="arrow right"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- more html -->
</section>
```

Here is how it looks at 250%, as you can see it hits the 2133 width media query:

[image]

And here is the arrow rendering correctly but also targeting the same media query:

[image]

How do I make `right: -25px;` ONLY when at 250% zoom?

Comment: Are you literally asking about the zoom on desktop browser when using the standard zooming behaviour? You should not count on an edge case such as this, and modern browsers (like safari's zooming with double tap) actually dont change the 'zoom level' while doing so. Actually hitting `Cmnd+` or `Ctrl+` to zoom is not standard behaviour and seems hard to correct and work with. Things break when zooming like that anyhow.

Comment: @somethinghere It doesn't matter what I should or shouldn't do. I was tasked with fixing this issue.

Comment: If you want to target `2133px` or wider, you should use `min-width`, not `max-width`. I think that might be the problem.

Comment: @DavidTunnell It _does_ matter. You have been sent on a fools errant. Zooming like that is _not_ standard, or common and will make many things go weird - if you want to correct for a use case that 99.999% of the people don't have, then you are wasting/asked to waste resources on something that benefits barely anyone or anything.

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you care about the zooming factor you should use `em` based mediaqueries to have your layout stay consistent when the user zooms in or out: http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/#relative

in your case, if you want to guess how many pixels equal the zooming factor, assuming it's 2133px you can write the following media query:

```
@media (width:2133px) {}
```

which kicks in only when the width is equal to 2133px, but that's not a good approach